# Vulkan Phong shader problem

Tags: c++, 3d, glsl, glm, vulkan

Light increases its intensity as it come closer the origin model.

Vertex Shader:

```
layout(push_constant) uniform MVPConst{
    mat4 m;
    mat4 v;
    mat4 p; 
} mvp;

layout(location = 0) in vec3 inPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 inColor;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 inTexCoord;
layout(location = 3) in vec3 inNormal;

layout(location = 0) out vec3 fragColor;
layout(location = 1) out vec2 fragTexCoord;
layout(location = 2) out vec3 normal;
layout(location = 3) out vec3 vP;
layout(location = 4) out vec3 vD;
layout(location = 5) out vec3 wP;
layout(location = 6) out vec3 fragPos;

void main(){
    vec4     wP = mvp.m * vec4(inPosition,1.0f);
    mat4    mat = mvp.p * mvp.v;
    gl_Position = mat * wP + vec4(.0,.5,.0,0);

            normal = normalize(mat3(mvp.m) * inNormal);
      fragTexCoord = inTexCoord;
         fragColor = inColor;
                vP = vec3(mvp.v[3][0], mvp.v[3][1], mvp.v[3][2]);
                vD = normalize(vP - wP.xyz);
}
```

Frag Shader:

```
#version 450

#define PI 3.14159265359

layout(binding = 0) uniform UBO{
    vec4  vP;
  vec4  vD;
  vec4  lP;
    float time;
    uvec2 res;
    float sharp;
    mat4  vM;
    mat4  invvM;
} ubo;

layout(binding = 1) uniform sampler2DArray texSampler;

layout(location = 0) in vec3 fragColor;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 fragTexCoord;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 normal;
layout(location = 3) in vec3 vP;
layout(location = 4) in vec3 vD;//Maybe problem
layout(location = 5) in vec3 wP;
layout(location = 6) in vec3 fragPos;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 outColor;

uvec2 res     = ubo.res;
float time    = ubo.time;

vec3 specular(){
    vec3 diffuseLight = vec3(1.);
    vec3 specularLight = vec3(.0);
    vec3 surfaceNormal = normalize(normal);

    vec3 cameraPosWorld = ubo.invvM[3].xyz;
    vec3 viewDirection = normalize(cameraPosWorld - wP);

    vec3 directionToLight = ubo.lP.xyz - wP.xyz;
    float attenuation = 1.0 / dot(directionToLight, directionToLight); // distance squared
    directionToLight = normalize(directionToLight);

    float cosAngIncidence = max(dot(surfaceNormal, directionToLight), 0);
    vec3 intensity = vec3(1.,0.,0.) * attenuation * 1.5;

    diffuseLight += intensity * cosAngIncidence;

    vec3 halfAngle = normalize(directionToLight + viewDirection);
    float blinnTerm = dot(surfaceNormal, halfAngle);
    blinnTerm = clamp(blinnTerm, 0, 1);
    blinnTerm = pow(blinnTerm, 512.0); // higher values -> sharper highlight
    specularLight += intensity * blinnTerm;

    vec3 color = texture(texSampler,vec3(fragTexCoord,2)).rgb;
    vec3 ambient = .2 * color;
    return ambient * diffuseLight;
}

void main(){
    vec2 vpuv = fragPos.xy / res;
    vpuv.y    = 1. - vpuv.y;

    outColor.rgb = specular();
}
```

cpp code:

```
if(_camera.ang.x > 360.f)      _camera.ang.x = 0.f;
    else if(_camera.ang.x < 0.f)   _camera.ang.x = 360.f;
    if(_camera.ang.y > 89.f)     _camera.ang.y = 89.f;
    else if(_camera.ang.y < -89.f) _camera.ang.y = -89.f;
    if(_camera.ang.z > 360.f)     _camera.ang.z =  0.f;
    else if(_camera.ang.z <  0.f)  _camera.ang.z = 360.f;


    _camera.dir.x = cos(glm::radians(_camera.ang.x)) * cos(glm::radians(_camera.ang.y));
    _camera.dir.y = sin(glm::radians(_camera.ang.x)) * cos(glm::radians(_camera.ang.y));
    _camera.dir.z = sin(glm::radians(_camera.ang.y));
    _camera.dir   = glm::normalize(_camera.dir);

    objAng.second = vec3(0.f,1.f,1.f);
    glm::mat4 m      = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), radians(sharpness), objAng.second);
          m      = glm::translate(m,obju->pos);
    glm::mat4 v      = glm::lookAt(_camera.pos, _camera.pos + _camera.dir, glm::vec3(0.f,0.f,1.f));
    glm::mat4 p       = glm::perspective(glm::radians(60.f), _swapChnExtent.width / (float) _swapChnExtent.height, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
          p[1][1] *= -1;

    _camera.view = v;

    _camera.invview[0][0] = _camera.view[0][0];
    _camera.invview[0][1] = _camera.view[1][0];
    _camera.invview[0][2] = _camera.view[2][0];
    _camera.invview[1][0] = _camera.view[0][1];
    _camera.invview[1][1] = _camera.view[1][1];
    _camera.invview[1][2] = _camera.view[2][1];
    _camera.invview[2][0] = _camera.view[0][2];
    _camera.invview[2][1] = _camera.view[1][2];
    _camera.invview[2][2] = _camera.view[2][2];
    _camera.invview[3][0] = _camera.pos.x;
    _camera.invview[3][1] = _camera.pos.y;
    _camera.invview[3][2] = _camera.pos.z;
MVP pconst;
    pconst.m = m;
    pconst.v = v;
    pconst.p = p;

    vkCmdPushConstants(info.cmdBuf,_graphxPlineLayt,VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT,0,sizeof(MVP),&pconst);
    vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(info.cmdBuf,VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS,_graphxPlineLayt,0,1,&_descrSets[_crntFram],0,nullptr);

    vkCmdDrawIndexed(info.cmdBuf,static_cast<uint32_t>(obju->inds.size()),1,0,0,0);
```

cpp code2:

```
UBO ubo{};
  ubo.vP    = glm::vec4(_camera.pos,1.f);
  ubo.vD    = glm::vec4(_camera.dir,1.f);
  ubo.lP    = glm::vec4(lightPos,1.f);
  ubo.time  = time;
  ubo.sharp = sharpness;
  ubo.vM    = _camera.view;
  ubo.invvM = _camera.invview;

  if(_framBufRsz || _isInitialized){
    ubo.res = vec2(_swapChnExtent.width,_swapChnExtent.height);
  }

  void* data;
  vkMapMemory(_device,_unifBufsMems[crntImg],0,sizeof(ubo),0,&data);
  memcpy(data,&ubo,sizeof(ubo));
  vkUnmapMemory(_device,_unifBufsMems[crntImg]);
```

---

https://pasteboard.co/2XQxHWfsnZJZ.jpg
https://pasteboard.co/wNDwXVUVeazO.jpg
https://pasteboard.co/SJ87c1aHOXiv.jpg
https://pasteboard.co/D8hSSB7D2mtY.jpg

Position of light equal to camera position

Comment: I cleaned and reorganized code, and now its working!

Answer (score 0):

Final fragment shader

````
#version 450

#define PI 3.14159265359

layout(binding = 0) uniform UBO{
    vec4  vP;
  vec4  vD;
  vec4  lP;
    float time;
    uvec2 res;
    float sharp;
    mat4  vM;
    mat4  invvM;
} ubo;

layout(binding = 1) uniform sampler2DArray texSampler;

layout(location = 0) in vec3 fragColor;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 fragTexCoord;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 fragNormal;
layout(location = 3) in vec3 fragPosWorld;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 outColor;

uvec2 res  = ubo.res;
float time = ubo.time;

vec3 specular(){
    vec3  diffuseLight = vec3(1.);
    vec3 specularLight = vec3(.0);
    vec3 surfaceNormal = normalize(fragNormal);

    vec3 cameraPosWorld = ubo.invvM[3].xyz;
    vec3  viewDirection = normalize(cameraPosWorld - fragPosWorld);

    vec3 directionToLight = ubo.lP.xyz - fragPosWorld.xyz;
    float     attenuation = 1.0 / dot(directionToLight, directionToLight);
         directionToLight = normalize(directionToLight);

    float cosAngIncidence = max(dot(surfaceNormal, directionToLight), 0);
    vec3        intensity = vec3(.992,.647,.059) * attenuation * 1.5;
             diffuseLight += intensity * cosAngIncidence;

    vec3  halfAngle  = normalize(directionToLight + viewDirection);
    float blinnTerm  = dot(surfaceNormal, halfAngle);
          blinnTerm  = clamp(blinnTerm, 0, 1);
          blinnTerm  = pow(blinnTerm,16.0);
      specularLight += intensity * blinnTerm;

    vec3   color = texture(texSampler,vec3(fragTexCoord,2)).rgb;
    vec3 ambient = .2 * color;

    return ambient * diffuseLight + specularLight * color;
}

void main(){
    vec2 vpuv = gl_FragCoord.xy / res;
    vpuv.y    = 1. - vpuv.y;

    outColor.rgb = specular();
}
```
````

Comment: This answer would be more useful to future readers struggling with similar problems if you explained what you changed and how it fixed the problem.